# How do I position a DataGridView to a specific row (so that the selected row is at the top)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, user-interface

I have an application with a DataGridView on it and I would like to position the rows such that a specific row is at the top of the list.

I don't want a sort, I want a way to programmatically tell the DataGridView "scroll to the Nth row."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)?

Comment: Holy cow. Where do they come up with these names? And I don't think I ever would have noticed this one, scrolling through that huge list of methods for DataGridView.

Answer (score 12):

The DataGridView has a property called: FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex. Set that, and the row will then be at the top of the list.

Comment: No sweat, he can use the rep more than I can :-P j/k

Comment: Hey man, if you're going to answer questions like these, you know some jacka$$ (like me) will make fun :-P

Comment: ;-p besides, no amount of votes will help me due to the rep cap - but this way around, I get +15 (the most I can get), and you get +20, and everyone is happy ;-p