# DataGridView First Column Always Bigger

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make the first row of the DataGridView to be bigger. I tried to use OnScroll but it does not always hit the mark. Is there a change row first index event that I can use in place of OnScroll?

```
private int lastRow = -1;
private void dgvN_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int firstVisibleRow = dgvN.HitTest(dgvN.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight,
        dgvN.RowHeadersWidth).RowIndex;

    if (lastRow != firstVisibleRow && firstVisibleRow != -1)
    {
        dgvN.Rows[firstVisibleRow].Height = 50;
        if (lastRow != -1)
        {
            dgvN.Rows[lastRow].Height = 20;
        }
        lastRow = firstVisibleRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to always make the first visible row bigger? So after scrolling the new row at the top of the grid is increased in height? I can't think of a good way to do this, so may I ask why you need it incase I can think of a good alternative approach?

Comment: Hmmm... actually it is in the specs to always allow the first item to be highlighted because it contains multi line text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int firstVisibleRow = dgvN.HitTest(dgvN.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight,
    dgvN.RowHeadersWidth).RowIndex;
```

to

```
int firstVisibleRow = dgvN.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
```

(at least, I think this is the behavior you want based on how your code behaved when pasted into my test project and your comment about "it does not always hit the mark")

Comment: Wow, I've been using the DGV for literally years and never noticed that property! +1

Comment: Looks like I found out about that property on this site in July '09 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155418/how-do-i-position-a-datagridview-to-a-specific-row-so-that-the-selected-row-is ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked but I guess I should perform the process together with DataBound event too in case the item increased and decreased.