# DataGridView equivalent to DataGrid.NavigateTo()

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there a DataGridView equivalent to DataGrid.NavigateTo()?  I thought that DataGridView.SelectedColumns[] would do it but it isn't equivalent.

Comment: What I am trying to do is replace this DataGrid code with DataGridView code but nothing seems to work:  this.dataGridView1.NavigateTo(0, "");  Everything I use gives me a "only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."

Comment: You might want to check out [Differences Between the Windows Forms DataGridView and DataGrid Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)?

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155432/95573) solution if you have hidden rows in your `DataGridView`.