# Clarification on how to select particular row in datagrid view

Tags: c#, winforms

Using c#, winforms

I want the user to type a number in a textbox. If the number is contained in the first column of my datagrid view, then that row should get highlighted, or pop up, or the datagridview scrolls down to it so the user can see it (you guys get my intention)

I was going around SO on how to achieve this and I was trying a particular technique but **I get the error : " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** for the variable searchVal In the if statement of my code below:

```
 private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String searchVal = textBox1.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
                {
                    // Also Is this how to make the row highlighted?
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean `for the variable searchVal`?  The initialization or the line with `Contains(searchVal)`?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Contains(searchVal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `null` value for cell, considering you have atleast one cell in your row, you check should be:

```
 if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null &&
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
```

You can also add a check for checking Cell Count like:

```
 if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count > 0 &&
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null &&
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
```

Comment: This works as an answer thanks, but a somewhat related question: How Can I when selecting the whole row, scroll down to it? Say the Row selected is way down below and the user has to scroll to it. Is there any way to scroll to the specific row containing the searchVal?

Comment: @Newuser you can use the DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can follow this link for your scrolling requirement based on the match http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795181/how-do-i-position-a-datagridview-to-a-specific-row-so-that-the-selected-row-is

Comment: @Rizwan I tried to use the approach but I don't know how to implement it properly: This is what I'm trying:
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                         dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
But I get an error saying the index was out of range

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your dataGridView1 for the option "add rows" because with it cause the n+1 items count, when the for is performed goes to n+1 which is null,also can make all of the above.

reagrding the focus you need to change

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

to

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, i];
break;
```

because you are trying to focus the row I guess

best regards

Comment: the original problem is solved but now I have another question. How would I use the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property in my code to scroll to the selected row?

Comment: try this dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index;